# How to convert byte[] to ObjectParameter in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, byte

I have a byte[] and wanna convert it to object parameter in asp.net.

```
byte[] version =98471574580;
```

and I have One method that wants "ObjectParametere version".I must convert  byte[] version to
ObjectParametere.

Comment: Where exactly are you having problems? `var objParam = new ObjectParameter("version", version);` would seem to generate an ObjectParameter but without context it is unclear if this is what you want and seems too obvious to be actually the answer...

Comment: @chris: Thank You ,I works,Please write it as an answer that I will mark it

Comment: I've done it now with the details of how I came to that answer to help you in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do this has a few steps that if you follow in future shoudl save you needing to ask this sort of question again.

1) Look at the documentation for the class you want to use. It is found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectparameter(v=vs.110).aspx googleing for "ObjectParameter" returns it as top hit for me. Google might have noticed me doing a lot of MSDN searches though and bumping them to the top so if in doubt try adding MSDN or c# to the search.

2) Look for how to create an instance of the object. This would usually be through constructors. Sometimes you may use static methods but constructors are usual and in fact there are two here we can consider.

3) Decide which constructor to use. One takes a name and a type. One takes a name and a value. Since we have a value this seems like the one to choose.

4) Call the constructor you have decided to use and assign it to a variable (or use it directly in your code). In this case the syntax would be `var objParam = new ObjectParameter("version", version);`.

Some of these steps might be short circuited. For example if you are programming in Visual Studio then typing `new ObjectParameter(` should then offer intellisense help on what constructors are available, saving the need to look the documentation up online.